# how to enable self sizing cell for tableviewcell retrieved from XIB in IOS8

Tags: iphone, ios8, nib, uitableview

I have an prototype `UITableViewCell` that I am not able to accomodate in the tableviewcontroller storyboard due to lack of space from having multiple cells in the tableviewcontroller and hence created a separate XIB file to define the prototype cell to hold an imageview.

However, I find that the self-sizing of the cell feature of IOS8 works for the prototype cells defined in the `UITableViewController` but not for the `tableviewcell` loaded from the xib. The imageview is spread over multiple rows.

tableview snapshot of the issue: 
[image]

I have set the autolayout size constraints on all cells.

Any advice on how to enable the imageview from nib to be a self sizing cell would be helpful.